# Grafana Loki HTTP API parameter "since"

Tags: grafana-loki, grafana-api

I'm doing Grafana Loki HTTP API queries, specifically [`query_range`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/api/#query-loki-over-a-range-of-time) ones which produce stream responses. The parameters listed for such queries are:

1. `query`
2. `limit`
3. `start`
4. `end`
5. `since`
6. `direction`

I've got 5 of the 6 working:

```js
const url = new URL('http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/query_range');

/* query */
url.searchParams.set('query', '{job="bob_job", branch="master"}');
/* limit */
url.searchParams.set('limit', '500');
/* start */
let start = new Date();
start.setHours(start.getHours() - 4);
url.searchParams.set('start', start.toISOString());
/* end */
let end = new Date();
end.setHours(end.getHours() - 2);
url.searchParams.set('end', end.toISOString());
/* since */
// url.searchParams.set('since', '5m');
/* direction */
url.searchParams.set('direction', 'forward');

console.log(url.toString());
fetch(url.toString(), {
    method: 'POST',
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((obj) => {
        console.log(obj);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

But `since` doesn't work. (Even if I comment out `start` and `end`.) I add it, and there's no error message. There's just no effect.

Moreover, I'm hard-pressed to find examples of other people's queries using the `since` parameter. What's up with it?